# MVC: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-2, foreign-keys

I have two tables that are supposed to be related.

[image]

Tables and Coloums Specification

Primary key table
ProductCategory
ProductCategoryID

Foreign key table
SubProductCategory2
ProductCategoryID

In the controller I have the following methods when creating sub category...

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ViewBag.ProductCategory = db.ProductCategories.OrderBy(p =>  
  p.ProductCategoryID).ToList();
  ViewBag.SubProductCategory2 = db.SubProductCategory2.OrderBy(a => 
  a.ProductCategoryID).ToList();

  var PC2 = new SubProductCategory2();
  return View(PC2);
} 

public ActionResult Create(SubProductCategory2 Createsubcat2, 
FormCollection values)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.AddToSubProductCategory2(Createsubcat2);
    db.SaveChanges(); 
      //error pointing here and the full error message I am getting is...
     /*error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
     * The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
     * "FK_SubProductCategory2_ProductCategory". The conflict occurred in  
     * database "MyHouseDB", table "dbo.ProductCategory", column 
     * 'ProductCategoryID'. The statement has been terminated.*/    
     return RedirectToAction("/");
   }

   ViewBag.ProductCategory = db.ProductCategories.OrderBy(p => 
   p.ProductCategoryID).ToList();
   ViewBag.SubProductCategory2 = db.SubProductCategory2.OrderBy(a => 
   a.ProductCategoryID).ToList();

   return View(Createsubcat2);
  }
 ViewBag.ProductCategory = db.ProductCategories.OrderBy(p => 
    p.ProductCategoryID).ToList();
    ViewBag.SubProductCategory2 = db.SubProductCategory2.OrderBy(a => 
    a.ProductCategoryID).ToList();
    return View(Createsubcat2);
```

in the views I have the following code...

```
<div class="editor-label">
  @Html.LabelForModel()
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.DropDownList("CategoryName", new   
   SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["ProductCategory"], 
   "ProductCategoryID", "CategoryName"))
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductCategory.CategoryName)
```

Could some tell me how to solve the The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint error message. Correct me if I'm wrong, have I created the relationship between two tables incorrectly or the problem else where? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. It was my sql database design not MVC coding side. I removed CategoryName column from SubCategory table. I could have felt the CategoryName as long as Allow Null was set to true. There was no point in doing that has PrimaryKey had been setup correctly for the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when the following conditions are true 1) The value that you selected for "ProductCategoryID" is not present in the "ProductCategory" table OR 2) The product category table is empty.

Does you have values in the product category table?

What value are you choosing for ProductCategoryID?

Comment: Strictly speaking 2 implies 1... The relationship there means "Each SubProductCategory belongs to a ProductCategory". 

So you cannot create a SubProductCategory without setting a valid productCategoryID. That means the ProductCategory must already exist in the table, so you must create it first.

Comment: Yes ProductCategory already exits which shows in the dropdown list. So the question I am asking when creating SubCategory is why doesn't the data gets saved when selecting value from dropdown menu?