# MVC - Adding data into linker tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a registration form that allows a school to register. In addition to the obvious login and general details the school can pick from a list of facilities and accreditations that they have.

My data is displayed lovely and binded correctly.

**Problem** Entering the data into the linker tables does not work it throws an error in both the different ways that I have tried:

**Method1:**

```
MembershipUser membershipUser = null;

if (schoolRegisterModel != null)
{
    if (null != DB)
    {
        school SchoolUser = new school();

        SchoolUser.username = schoolRegisterModel.UserName;
        SchoolUser.email = schoolRegisterModel.Email;

        string sPassowrdSalt = Security.Instance().CreateSalt();

        SchoolUser.password = Security.Instance().CreatePasswordHash(schoolRegisterModel.Password, sPassowrdSalt);

        SchoolUser.password_salt = sPassowrdSalt;

        ..More data etc..

        foreach (var item in schoolRegisterModel.Facilities)
        {
            if (item.@checked)
            {
                school_facility sf = new school_facility();
                sf.facility_id = item.facility_id;
                SchoolUser.school_facility.Add(sf);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in schoolRegisterModel.Accreditations)
        {
            if (item.@checked)
            {
                school_accreditation sa = new school_accreditation();
                sa.accreditation_id = item.accreditation_id;
                SchoolUser.school_accreditation.Add(sa);
            }
        }

        DB.schools.Add(SchoolUser);
        DB.SaveChanges();
```

**Error:** {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_school_facility_facility\". The conflict occurred in database \"MYDB\", table \"dbo.facility\", column 'facility_id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Also - Do I need to manually retrieve the soon to be school ID that will be generated based on this insert. This method avoids entering data directly into the linker tables using only the primary table (school).

**Method2:**

Same code again apart from trying to update the primary tables (school) accreditation and facilities collection directly, I manually update the linker tables seperately using the latest primary key generated by the previous query, code for this is as follows:

MembershipUser membershipUser = null;

```
if (schoolRegisterModel != null)
{
    if (null != DB)
    {
        school SchoolUser = new school();

        SchoolUser.username = schoolRegisterModel.UserName;
        SchoolUser.email = schoolRegisterModel.Email;

        string sPassowrdSalt = Security.Instance().CreateSalt();

        SchoolUser.password = Security.Instance().CreatePasswordHash(schoolRegisterModel.Password, sPassowrdSalt);

        SchoolUser.password_salt = sPassowrdSalt;

        ..More data etc..

        // Linker data for facilities and accreditations.
        // Facilities
        foreach (var item in schoolRegisterModel.Facilities)
        {
            if (item.@checked)
            {
                school_facility sf = new school_facility();
                sf.facility_id = item.facility_id;
                sf.school_id = SchoolUser.school_id;
                DB.school_facility.Add(sf);
            }
        }

        // Accreditations
        foreach (var item in schoolRegisterModel.Accreditations)
        {
            if (item.@checked)
            {
                school_accreditation sa = new school_accreditation();
                sa.accreditation_id = item.accreditation_id;
                sa.school_id = SchoolUser.school_id;
                DB.school_accreditation.Add(sa);
            }
        }

        m_DB.SaveChanges();
```

**Error:** {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_school_facility_facility\". The conflict occurred in database \"MYDB\", table \"dbo.facility\", column 'facility_id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

If you guys have any idea where I am going wrong then please do let me know. There seem to be examples of updating linker table date (which I will need at some point anyway) but can't find an example of my problem...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have found the answer:

[MVC: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283376/mvc-the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint)

My data being pulled through was basically not containing the correct foreign key value (0 - which didn't exist) and quite rightly my DB was throwing the error. Sorry for wasting time to whoever read and thanks for your time. I hope this can help somebody else.

Joe